# Javascript: Changing variable on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript file linked to index.html like below:

```
<script src='game.js' type='text/javascript'>
</script>
```

Assume that `game.js` contains:

```
 var speed = ...;
```

Along with some other content.

I have 3 buttons on the HTML page that when clicked I want to change the variable `speed` in the javascript. Once clicked I want all 3 buttons to be disabled or hidden until the reset button is clicked. Any idea how I go about this?

Comment: Sorry guys I should of stated I cant use jQuery as its for a University assignment jQuery not allowed. Also just to inform you im making a HTML 5 Canvas snake type game the buttons are to set the speed of the snake for difficulty.

Comment: @Mark - if it's for an assignment you should also tag as `homework` so that people don't provide a complete answer.  That would be cheating.

Comment: @Tomalek - both are true.  In this instance he *should have* tagged as homework and in all cases when it is for an assignment, one *should* tag [it] as homework.

Comment: In either case, I'm really surprised that he's doing HTML5 stuff at school. +1 for his university!!

Answer (score 1):

Using pure HTML/JavaScript, here's what I would do:

```
<form name="form1">
  <span id="buttons">
    <input type="button" name="button1" value="Speed1"/>
    <input type="button" name="button2" value="Speed2"/>
    <input type="button" name="button3" value="Speed3"/>
  </span>
  <input name="reset" type="reset"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var speed, buttonsDiv=document.getElementById("buttons");
  for (var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
    var button = document.form1["button" + i];
    button.onclick = function() {
      speed = this.value;
      alert("OK: speed=" + speed);
      buttonsDiv.style.display = 'none';
    };
  }
  document.form1.reset.onclick = function() {
    speed = null;
    alert("Speed reset!");
    buttonsDiv.style.display = 'inline';
    return true;
  };
</script>
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/maerics/TnTuD/

Comment: You forgot to wait until the DOM has rendered.

Comment: @Tomalak: right, I forgot that important detail, I suppose the contents of the script tag should be wrapped in `window.onload = function() { ... };`.

Answer (score 0):

Create functions within your javascript files that attach to the `click` events of each button.

The functions would change the variable you want.

```
aButtonelement.addEventListener('click',functionToChangeVariable,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, use jQuery.

```
$("#idofbutton").click(function () {
    // change variables here
});
```

Or you could register an event:

```
document.getElementById("idofbutton").addEventListener('click', function () {
    // change variables here
}, false);
```

[Source](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents)

Comment: for backward xbrowser compat, you should add a FALSE as argument # 3

Comment: Good catch.  I usually develop for HTML5 compatible browsers, so I generally don't bother with this.

Answer (score 0):

Include the following in your Javascript file:

```
function DisableButtons() {
   speed = 100;
   document.getElementById("btn_1").disabled = true;
   document.getElementById("btn_2").disabled = true;
   document.getElementById("btn_3").disabled = true;
}

function EnableButtons() {
   document.getElementById("btn_1").disabled = false;
   document.getElementById("btn_2").disabled = false;
   document.getElementById("btn_3").disabled = false;
}
```

In your HTML, assign the following onClick events:

```
<button onClick="DisableButtons();">Button 1</button>
<button onClick="DisableButtons();">Button 2</button>
<button onClick="DisableButtons();">Button 3</button>    
<button onClick="EnableButtons();">Reset</button>
```

Comment: onClick is not the best route.  Event listeners should be used instead.

Comment: @tjameson: I agree, though it'll probably do for a homework assignment.

Comment: Ah, I missed the part about it being a homework assignment. Still, it's good practice.

Comment: Homework? Oh man, there should be some sort of flashing red light when questions are tagged with "homework".  I completely missed that.

Answer (score 0):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/qMRmn/

Basically, `speed` is a global variable, and clicking a button with the class `set-speed` class will set the speed to a new value, and disable all of the `set-speed` buttons.  Clicking the `reset` button will re-enable them.

The code should be fairly self explanatory.